# PATCH calendar GAPI error: Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-calendar-api

I'm having problem using the PATCH request with calendar GAPI. When I supply a body to the request, I get an error 400: Request contains an invalid argument.

```
 code: 400,
 errors: [
   {
     message: 'Request contains an invalid argument.',
     domain: 'global',
     reason: 'invalidArgument'
   }
 ]
```

If I don't add a body to the request, the request works, I receive a status 200, with the unchanged data of the event as expected, so I think authentification works fine and the problem is simply related to the body of the request.

Here is a simplified version of my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

```
 const updatedEvent = {
   summary: 'My new title',
 };
 const jsonBody = JSON.stringify(updatedEvent);

 // Set JWT and PATCH modification on user calendar
 const oauth2Client = new JWT({
   subject: SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
   keyFile: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS,
   scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events']
 });
 const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${calendarID}/events/${calendarEventId}?alt=json`;
 await oauth2Client.request({
   url,
   method: 'PATCH',
   body: jsonBody,
 })
 .then((res) => {
   console.log(res);
 })
 .catch((error) => {
   console.log(error); 
   throw Error('GAPI PATCH request error')
 });
```

**FIX:**
Working implementation with npm googleapis library

```
import { google } from 'googleapis';
...
await google.calendar('v3').events.patch({
  auth: oauth2Client,
  calendarId: calendarId,
  eventId: calendarEventId,
  requestBody: {
    summary: 'New title',
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It should be `resource` instead of `body`

For testing purposes to obtain the right syntax you can

1. Test a request with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch)
2. Test the request with the gapi client as proposed by the `Try this API` whwen you expand it nd choose `JAVASCRIPT`
   `
   In your case:

```
    return gapi.client.calendar.events.patch({
      "calendarId": "XXX",
      "eventId": "YYY",
      "alt": "json",
      "resource": {
        "summary": "My new title"
      }
    })
```

Once you have the syntax right, you can transfer it to the request with the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already did investigate with the "Try this API" and the request payload is simply `{"summary":"My new title"}`, I can't find how to fix the syntax with `resource` anywhere.

Comment: I did a similar implementation as you suggested in 2. with npm googleapis library and it works now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can find the resource if you expand the Try this API dialog and switch to JAVASCRIPT.